# Run function with linux cron job in Wordpress

Tags: wp-cron, cron

I know that WordPress has a faux cron that is called like so when a user visits the page.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_activation');
add_action('my_hourly_event', 'do_this_hourly');

function my_activation() {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event');
}

function do_this_hourly() {
    // do something every hour
}
```

I want to use linux cron like so:

```
*/5 * * * * * /usr/local/bin/php/ /Path/to/file
```

The problem is that if that file is like this:

```
<?php 

function do_something() {

  echo 'Hello World';

}

do_something();
```

Do something function is called every time I reload the page. What I need is a way to specify with linux cron so that do_something() is only called when it is time to run cron. So the file should just have the function definition of do_something() it shouldn't call the function directly.

```
<?php 

 function do_something() {

   echo 'Hello World';

 }
```

Comment: why not just get the time of day stored in a variable and then use that on a switch statement where if the time is xx then it'll do it?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing one key component.

Add this to your `wp-config.php`: `define( 'DISABLE_WP_CRON', true );`

Here are some other helpful constants for your `wp-config.php`: https://gist.github.com/MikeNGarrett/e20d77ca8ba4ae62adf5

Answer (score 1):

Your cron jobs only run when you tell them to.

- 1: Minute (0-59)
- 2: Hours (0-23)
- 3: Day (0-31)
- 4: Month (0-12 [12 == December])
- 5: Day of the week(0-7 [7 or 0 == sunday])
- /path/to/command - Script or command name to schedule

---

```
* * * * * command to be executed
- - - - -
| | | | |
| | | | ----- Day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
| | | ------- Month (1 - 12)
| | --------- Day of month (1 - 31)
| ----------- Hour (0 - 23)
------------- Minute (0 - 59)
```

---

But it could be possible to pass the function name to your PHP like

```
1 2 3 4 5 /path/to/command arg1 arg2
```

Then, in your PHP file, only run the task if the argument was passed using `$_SERVER` or `$_GET`.

- [HowTo: Add Jobs To cron Under Linux or UNIX?](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/)
- [Cron Jobs calling a PHP script with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872679/cron-jobs-calling-a-php-script-with-variables)
- [Crontab Guru](https://crontab.guru/)

Comment: Did this help at all? Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: Can you please give me an example of the Script File?